# How to use query builder to retrieve array values from different tables?

Tags: php, laravel-5

Following is the code snippet that I have used in my controller:

```
 public function index(Request $request)
    { 
        $query = DB::table('project_files')->select('project_id')->get()->toArray();
        dd($query);
        return view ( 'filesync/listfiles' )->with ( $query);
    }
```

So when I try passing the values into the view, I get an array which consists of the project_id from the project_files table. What I would want to do now is to retrieve the project_names of these project_ids, stored in the projects table.I need to use the project_id for the same , but am unable to understand how to relate these using query builder.Any help would be appreciated, meaning how do I use the array values in the query retrieving project names from projects table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#introduction) which is the ideal way or you can use a [`leftJoin`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#joins) with your query:

```
DB::table('project_files')->select('project_files.project_id')->leftJoin('projects', 'project_files.project_id', '=', 'projects.project_id')->get()->toArray();
```

and replace the column name respectively to the correct values.

Another suggestion I would make is to actually make use of the ***M*** in *M*VC by defining [models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions) for your table instead of using the db facade.

**Note:** Don't forget to include the columns you wish to select within your `select` function.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply.Do you think that setting up relationships could be a better approach to this, I find query builder messy, but since the number of tables to be dealt with increases, it somewhat ,makes the job easier, I don't happen to know much about eloquent though.Should I be considering that as well?

Comment: Eloquent, IMO, pretty much makes Laravel. So if you aren't using it when it is at your disposal it is quite a shame, as for the relationships, if you define them then it would save you from having to use `leftJoin` and you can just use `->with('relationship_name')`.